# count row numbers by using single sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query like `SELECT * table from etc order by something LIMIT 10` but in the same time I also want to know the TOTAL row results in the table. Do I need to do another sql?

Comment: You can do that using PHP by calling [mysqli_num_rows()](http://pk1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Comment: @AzizShaikh I want to know the total.

Comment: 'total' as in 'count' of the rows returned by your sql query OR 'sum' of values from the specific column?

Comment: You could use COUNT(*) aggregate function?

Comment: @Edper count and select can be use together?

Comment: @user3318525: by "total", you mean number of rows matching a filter clause independent of your limit...?

Comment: @user3318525 Yes, like `SELECT COUNT(*) as TotalRows FROM etc`. But if you are using php you could just simply use `SELECT * FROM etc` and then use `mysql_num_rows($query)`'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see total rows return by the query you use `mysqli_num_rows($sql)`

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from etc order by something LIMIT 10");

$total_rows = @mysqli_num_rows($sql);
```

**Edit :-** If you want total of specifc coloumn say 'id' you can do like this :-

```
$total = 0;

while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{

    $total = $total + $result['id'];

}

echo $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, I had to do another sql... Here is what I used to count the numbers of users (userid>16 was due to sueprusers and deleted accounts):

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) AS "Number of users"
FROM 
Users
where  userid>16
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using mysql use this:

```
    $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'usename', 'password');
    if (!$conn) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db('database_name');


    mysql_query('SELECT * table from etc order by something LIMIT 10');
    echo mysql_affected_rows();
```

Comment: I suspect the the result is 10? I want the TOTAL

Comment: are you using this for pagination?

Comment: @Karim Lahlou: please don't encourage the use of the old `mysql` extension and the "`die` on failed connections" routine.